# Sitecore Rocks Package Installation Error - "Could not find configuration node: databases/database[@id='live']"

Tags: packages, installation, sitecore-rocks

Getting this error when trying to install a package to my local Sitecore instance via Sitecore Rocks. I am not aware of a "live" database so I am not sure where this is coming from. I have checked the ShowConfig to ensure there is only core, master, web in the databases/database nodes. No "live" db in there.

[image: Error when I try installing]

Comment: It looks like the package is trying to find a database called live.

Comment: Have you checked anything weird like targets, etc. that might want to refer to a "live" DB?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As Geoff already pointed out; the package seems to contain content for a database called "live".

You can see (and remove, if you want) this by opening the package file. I'm using WinRAR for this example:

When opening up the package archive, you will find `package.zip`.

[image]

And opening that up, you will find a structure like this:

[image]

The "items" folder is the one you're after. In my example here; all I have are items in the "core" database - but presumably yours would have additional folders. Including one called "live".

[image]

You can rename or delete this folder (as appropriate, I don't know enough about your package to make that call), and the package should be able to roll on without issue.

Comment: Oh good catch. I was thinking it's the install of Sitecore Rocks itself

Comment: This makes total sense and worked. I got the packages as a pull-down from a Production environment from a "live" database. Once I got the packages from the "master" database they installed just fine.